# How paint.net accomplish it: show pixel coordinates when mouse is moving

Tags: c#, winforms

There is a picture in my winform, I want to show pixel coordinates when mouse is moving, and
whether zoom in or out, the same pixel's coordinates don't change, just like what paint.net does.
Appreciate for any idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to handle the [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove.aspx) event and get the location from `e.X` and `e.Y`.

You can divide the location by your zoom factor.

Answer (score 0):

about the mouse coordinate, you should use Matrix to track back mouse coordinate.

see: [Back track the mouse](https://web.archive.org/web/20121006140255/http://www.bobpowell.net/backtrack.htm)

Comment: This is only helpful if he's already using a `Matrix` for zoom and pan.  If he isn't, this will be less efficient than transforming it manually and won't actually do any good.

Comment: yes. agree. and i think Matrix is better way to do zoom staff.